# Что такое # перед селектором в CSS?

Tags: css

Что такое `#` перед селектором в CSS? Чем он отличается от `.` и как это называется, чтоб я смог статейки поискать

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: `id="foo"` -> `#foo { color: red; }`, `class="foo"` -> `.foo { color: red; }`

Comment: https://webref.ru/CSS#selectors - есть еще такая табличка)

Answer (score 1):

1. Селектор `#identifier` – соответствует элементу с атрибутом `id="identifier"`, как правило, "identifier" должен быть уникальным на странице
2. Селектор `.class-name` – соответствуют элементам, у которых в атрибуте `class` указан `class-name`

Селектор по идентификатору является более специфичным чем селектор по классу, поэтому более вероятно, что применятся свойства который указаны в нем, пример:

```css
#green {
  background-color:green;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.red {
  background-color:red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div id="green" class="red"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Comment: А там не железобетонный приоритет для всего? Что если `#`, то перебьет любые другие стили с классами... ( смутила фраза "более вероятно" )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, например `!important` на свойстве в классе